# Excel Online Erroring out

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-online, excel-online

We have been using Excel Online to get data from an On Premise SQL Server , The files have been opening fine for the last 3 years without any issues until last Thursday as shown below

[image: Excel Error]

We have not made any changes to the file for the last 3 years.

Can anyone suggest how we can get this to work or if there is any workaround by any chance?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is telling you problem here as far as I can see.

Comment: @Larnu Yes this started happening all of a sudden... can you please suggest any workaround how to get around the issue?